# Caclulate Fee on @solana/web3.js

Tags: solana-web3js

How to calculate the transaction fee using the library @solana/web3.js?
I found the interface [here](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/interfaces/FeeCalculator.html), but I don't know how to use it

Answer (score 1):

Given a message, you can use the [`getFeeForMessage()`](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/docs/src/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api.md#getfeeformessage) API on `Connection`.

```js
const transaction = new Transaction(/* ... */);

const response = await connection.getFeeForMessage(
  transaction.compileMessage(),
  'confirmed',
);
const feeInLamports = response.value;
```

Comment: See also, the tests for `getFeeForMessage`: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/ebe3d2d59d34f8d3c4d04ed42b4e8f958b2a6829/web3.js/test/connection.test.ts#L2319-L2349